# How to enable SignalR server side tracing on OWIN self host?

Tags: signalr, owin, self-hosting

I keep getting intermittent `No transport could be initialized successfully.` error in my OWIN self hosted application with SignalR and I haven't been able to find a problem yet, all transport types just fail silently during initialization sometimes.

I'm trying to enable logging and tracing on server side, but can't find how I can do it.

I've seen this article http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing
but I don't think I can do it with OWIN

How can I set up SignalR server side logging? I'm interested in iniitialization tracing - my client and server side method calls work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but I'm at least getting some trace after installing Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics nuget package and then:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.Properties["host.AppMode"] = "development";
        app.UseErrorPage(new Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics.ErrorPageOptions { ShowExceptionDetails = true });

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
```

This returns HTML to the client with a stack trace and some other useful info. Hope it helps.